# How to keep app running in background?

Tags: android

I am making an sms reader app .As soon as their is an incoming msg with the help of brodcast listener 
my activity receives the message and with the help of text to speech class it reads the msg.
Problem is as soon as their is an incoming msg, my activity comes in foreground.Can anyone help me how to make my app run in background only ? I am pasting my code for reference. Thanks !

```
MyBroadcastReceiver. java
package com.example.sms_reader;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;


public class MyBrodcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.d("tag1", "Receiver is activated");
        Log.d("tag2", "msg");
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 

        if (bundle != null)
        {   
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) 
            {
        messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]); 
            }
        for (SmsMessage message : messages) 
            {
                String msg = message.getMessageBody();
                long when = message.getTimestampMillis();  
                String from = message.getOriginatingAddress();  
                Log.d("tag2", msg);
                Log.d("tag3", from);
                Intent i = new Intent(arg0 ,Texttospeech.class);
                i.putExtra("msg", msg);
                i.putExtra("when", when);
                i.putExtra("from", from);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                arg0.startActivity(i); 
                Log.d("tag4", "intent called");

            }


        }
        else{
            Log.d("tag2", "bundle not received");
        }
    }

}


Texttospeech.java
package com.example.sms_reader;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;

public class Texttospeech extends Activity implements
TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
{

TextToSpeech tts ; 
String content;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("tag4", "INTENT RECEIVED");
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);    
    Intent data = getIntent();
    Log.d("tag5", "INTENT ");
    String msg = data.getStringExtra("msg");
    String from = data.getStringExtra("from");
    content = "You have received a message from" +from +"and it says"+msg;
    Log.d("tag6", content);
    speakOut(); 

};

private void speakOut() {


    tts.speak(content, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}   

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to shutdown!
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        // tts.setPitch(5); // set pitch level

        // tts.setSpeechRate(2); // set speech speed rate

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
        } 
        else {

            speakOut();
        }

                                         } 
    else 
    {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: As @tyczj mentions - show your code. It seems to me though that your `BroadcastReceiver` needs to create a `Notification` which the user can use to open your `Activity`.

Comment: Are you saying you don't want anything to appear and just want the SMS message to be read using TTS? If so, that isn't really a good design practice - the user should be allowed to choose when the message is read to them.

Comment: You can use notifications which tells the system to keep your app running!

Comment: @Eenvincible : A `Notification` doesn't keep an "app running" but it can be used to start various app components even if they are stopped - this is not the same thing.

Comment: @Sqounk- yes i don't want anything to appear , i just want my app to read the message.And if user want to change the settings he can click on my app launcher icon and can select the settings from their.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the text to speech activity that's why it pops up every time. If you want to keep it in background change your text to speech activity to service.